# Writing multiple data in CSV file using Bean Shell Post Processor in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I had a scenario where I need to write **correlation values** in a CSV file. And the easiest way I had come up with is the below code in answer section.

*More suggestions are appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
new File('FILEPATH/filename.csv') << vars.get('PARAM_1') << ',' << vars.get('PARAM_2') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

---

However this approach will work only if no concurrency assumed, if the PostProcessor will be executed by 2 or more concurrent threads you may run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when multiple threads will be writing into the same file resulting in data corruption.

So I would recommend declaring your `PARAM_1` and `PARAM_2` as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and storing them into a file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Flexible file writer looks more simple than any other way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [Flexible file writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) You can use that it is efficient and easy to implement explained [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks! I find this method much simple than others.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code in Bean Shell Post Processor

```
a = vars.get("PARAM_1"); // PARAM_1 is parameter/correlation variable
b = vars.get("PARAM_2"); // PARAM_2 is parameter/correlation variable
f = new FileOutputStream("FILEPATH/filename.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(a +","+ b);
f.close();
```